# How to make a Popup appear in a specific corner

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, uwp, popup

I want my `Popup` to always appear in a specific corner (lower right corner e.g.) no matter the size and the resolution of my `View`.

I tried using `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` but it's not really working.

Here's my code :

```
<Grid x:Name="Output" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1">
    <Popup x:Name="StandardPopup">
        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" 
            Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            BorderThickness="2" Width="500" Height="500">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <WebView x:Name="WebView1" Source="https://www.bing.com/" Width="490" Height="490" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a UserControl to help you achieve this.

**Create a new UserControl called TestPopup**

```xml
<UserControl
    ...
    >

    <Grid>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" 
            Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
            BorderThickness="2" Width="500" Height="500">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <WebView x:Name="WebView1" Source="https://www.bing.com/" Width="490" Height="490" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

The code-behind:

```cs
public sealed partial class TestPopup : UserControl
{
    private Popup _popup = null;
    public TestPopup()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        // If you need to top placement, please comment out the Width/Height statement below
        this.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
        this.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;

        //Assign the current control to the Child property of the popup. The Child property is what the popup needs to display.
        _popup = new Popup();
        _popup.Child = this;
    }
    public void ShowPopup()
    {
        _popup.IsOpen = true;
    }
    public void HidePopup()
    {
        _popup.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

**Use C# code references where needed**

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private TestPopup _popup = new TestPopup();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _popup.ShowPopup();
    }
}
```

To ensure that it is in the lower right corner at any width, you can listen to the page's `SizeChanged` event.

```cs
private void Page_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _popup.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
    _popup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
    // If you need to use the Width/Height of the page
    // _popup.Width = e.NewSize.Width;
    // _popup.Height = e.NewSize.Height;
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you, it's working pretty fine but there's one thing bothering me, when I change the `VerticalAlignment` value to `"Top"` the `Popup` goes inside the `Titlebar`, so I added`Margin="0 32 0 0"` to solve the problem but I wonder if it's the best solution.

Comment: Hi, In the code, the width and height of the user control are determined by the window, and the title bar is also part of the window. If you plan to put Popup on top, consider replacing the width and height of the window with the width and height of the Page.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the equivalent of `Window.Current.Bounds` for `Page` please?

Comment: Hi, please check my updated answer, I changed the contents of the Page_SizeChanged and TestPopup constructors

Answer (score 0):

Sadly [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup#examples) does not support Alignments you have to use the **Offset Values**

NOTE: Don't forget that you can use Bindings for Offsets and so get your wanted behavior with some Converter magic.

```
<Popup HorizontalOffset="20" 
       VerticalOffset="10">
    <!--Content-->
</Popup>
```